# Loading jars at run-time

Tags: java, classloader

I am having `comm.jar` and `RXTXComm.jar` for serial communication. I have both of these jars in my class-path.

Now, depending on a config parameter I should import appropriate jar at run-time.
Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can instanciate a class loader and load the jar file. The standard classloaders have all the functionality you need.

Good tutorials/links to start:

- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html
- http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18345.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they both have a superclass C

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

```
Class a;
if(foo)
    a = Class.forname("rxtx.somepackage.Someclass");
else
    a = Class.forname("comm.somepackage.SomeOtherclass");
C c = a.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CommDriver driver;
if (configA) {
    driver = (CommDriver) Class.forName("rxtx.driver.package").newInstance();
} else {
     driver = (CommDriver) Class.forName("com.sun.comm.Win32Driver").newInstance();
}
driver.initialize();
```